# how to create a spawner without destroying a gameobject

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

So I have ran across a problem while making my fps in unity. The code does everything I want it to but I sill have a game breaking problem.

First: in my game I have an orc that is in the scene then my spawner clones the object to where I want it

The problem: the original orc moves toward the player and when it's shot and ultimately destroyed the spawner can no longer clone it is there a way around this?

Thankyou to anyone who answers my question it's much appreciated because I am a beginner at unity and c# and js.

```
var Distance; 
var Target:Transform; 
var lookAtDistance = 25.0; 
var attackRange = 15.0; 
var moveSpeed = 5.0; 
var Damping = 6.0; 

function Update () { 
    Distance = Vector3.Distance(Target.position, transform.position); 
    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Target.position - transform.position); 

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * Damping); 
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

Comment: Your title and question do not match, but I believe what you are really wanting to do is to make a "Prefab" of that orc, and give the spawner a reference to that "prefab".

Comment: You need to create a new object so call the constructor.  List<string> myString = new List<string>() {"A","B","C"};   So to close list you simply do List<string> myString2 = new List<string>(myString);

Comment: @jdweng what does that have to do with this question?

Comment: @Eddge when i make it a prefab my script to make the enemy chase the player doesnt work

Comment: @JonBergeron What script?  I can't help you solve that issue if you don't show any code.  The way your question is written, if your orc that is in the scene dies you can no longer make new orcs, the only way to solve that is to make a prefab of them.  Or to create an object pool, set them to inactive, and activate and move them when you need them spawned.

Comment: @Eddge my code is in

Comment: Add it to your question in code tags, not a comment

Comment: @JonBergeron just from your code it appears you are assigning a follow transform to an object in the scene, you have no code for the orcs to detect the player nor do you have any method for getting the players transform... there are several ways to approach that problem.

Comment: @Eddge it works fine but when i make it a prefab i cant drag my player into the box for transform

Comment: @Eddge and when i make my player a prefab it runs to the original position then spins in that spot

Comment: @Jon well him not chasing the player is another problem, you will have to make a question for that.  I will update my answer with an alternative that you might be able to use instead of a prefab.

Comment: @JonBergeron I updated my answer take a look at the edit and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a prefab of your orc.  I would suggest making a folder in your Unity project, called Prefabs.  In your sceneview take the orc you are trying to spawn in your spawner, and drag the whole object into this folder.  This creates a prefab.

Now you can delete the orc from your scene. In order to spawn the orc, now you go to your spawners, and you drag the prefab the slot where you were spawning your orc.  So far Example:

```
public class SpawnPoint : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject creatureToSpawn;
    public void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    public void Spawn(GameObject ObjectToSpawn)
    {
        Instantiate(creatureToSpawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

In the inspector of this Spawner, where the script is located will be an element that you can drag your prefab into.

**EDIT:**
When you instantiate an object, you are making a clone of that object exactly how it is.  So if you instantiate a clone of an object, that has a script that has the player targetted, your now cloned object will also have the player targetted.  If you instantiate a clone of an inactive object, the clone will be inactive.  So your alternative is to make the original inactive and spawn it doing something like this:

```
public class randomSpawner : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject cloneObject;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(cloneObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            temp.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```